# Get Totalrecord Count of any document in MongoDb C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, robo3t

I am working on mongoDb task in which I need to fetch total records count of any document(table).

Previously, I wrote working code, as below:

```
var sortedFilteredPagingQuery = collection.Find(queryDoc).SetSortOrder(sortExpr);
var totalRecords = sortedFilteredPagingQuery.ToList().Count;
```

However, when I updated mongoDb and changed RoboMongo to Robo 3T, now it is not  working.

Comment: `'Then it is not working'` isn't exactly the best explanation of what went wrong... What is the error ? Also, only the update of mongoDb driver is what matters here. RoboMongo and Robo 3T are only Mongo management tools.

Comment: Do you get an error or does the count return 0?

Comment: it keeps loading.. it doesn't return any count.. Then I have to cancel the execution.